# Get a list of file paths created over a period of time in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to get a list of file paths created over a period of time in C++?

If using the command `find`, it is possible like following:

```sh
$ find ./* -mmin -2880 -mmin +1440
```

Comment: `std::system(find ./* -mmin -2880 -mmin +1440)`?

Comment: You can always look through the source code of e.g. GNU findutils to see what they do: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++17 provides [std::filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem).

It contains [std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator) which you can use to traverse all paths and filter them based on file time.

I do not see creation time, but there is [std::filesystem::last_write_time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time). Try search documentation for alternatives. It may turn out that you have to use some system specific API.

If you are limited to C++11 then use boost or fall back to system specific API.